# How do I select a schema based on a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider:

```
SET @PREFIX='DEV_';

SET @REFRESHDB=CONCAT(@PREFIX,'Refresh');

CREATE TABLE @REFRESHDB.`Metadata`
(
    `Key` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `Value` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Key`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO @REFRESDB.`Metadata` (`Key`, `Value`) VALUES ("Version", "0");
```

This does not seem to be valid: mysql comes back with:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@REFRESHDB.`Metadata`

As far as I can tell I've done things correctly according to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html). Yet MySQL says it's not allowed. Is this some limitation of MySQL (not allowing use of variables as identifiers) or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation states:

"User variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value"

You are trying to use the variable as an object.  This is not supported.

Comment: I don't see how what can be assigned to the variable controls where the variable can be used.

Comment: You're using it as an object, implying that the the value of `@REFRESHDB` is a schema object, not the string value it actually is.

Comment: I'm giving both you and Abe an upvote on this one. Without dynamic SQL (Abe gives us a way to do it with DSQL), this can't be done with the MySQL syntax, and this is actually a good thing in that it simplifies security and performance considerations.

For those who walk on the wild side, there is DSQL.

Answer (score 8):

You will have to use prepare statement/dynamic sql to do this.

This article goes over both of these in excellent detail:

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Try this:

```
SET @PREFIX='DEV_';

SET @REFRESHDB=CONCAT(@PREFIX,'Refresh');

SET @st = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', @REFRESHDB,'.`Metadata`
(
    `Key` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `Value` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Key`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB');

PREPARE tStmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE tStmt;


SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @PREFIX, '.`Metadata` (`Key`, `Value`) VALUES ("Version", "0")');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statement fails.

Comment: Oh I missed that, you will have to put that into a prepared statement as well.  I've updated it to put the create table into a prepared statement.

Comment: With that correction, what you have works, but for anyone who intends to implement this, be aware of security and performance considerations.

Dynamic SQL can be a bit of a black art.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE (IN DBname varchar(255)
                , IN AKey varchar(255)
                , IN AValue varchar(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE query VARCHAR(1000);
  -- First check the DBName against a list of allowed DBnames, 
  -- to prevent SQL-injection with dynamic tablenames.

  DECLARE NameAllowed BOOLEAN;
  SELECT 1 INTO NameAllowed WHERE DBName IN ('validDB1','validDB2');
  IF (NameAllowed = 1) THEN BEGIN

  -- DBName is in the whitelist, it's safe to continue.
    SET query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO '
                      ,DBName
                      ,'.MetaData (`key`,`value`) values (?,?));
    -- note the use of parameter placeholders, to prevent SQL-injection.
    PREPARE stmt FROM query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING Akey, AValue;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; -- clears the query and its result from the cache.
  END; END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It's failing on the CREATE TABLE statement, not the insert.